# Wordpress product Page not Found

Tags: wordpress, url, http-status-code-404, product

1

Came upon a problem with product links - everything was working, after installation of plugin Product Size Charts Plugin for WooCommerce and adding size attribute getting 404 on every product. Already deleted plugin and size attribute, but the problem is still there. Below is my htaccess and snap from permlinks settings. Checked some ways to fixing online but nothing seems to be working so far

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

[image]

Comment: Did you re-save permalink structure after plugin delete?

Comment: I hit save changes multiple times if that is what you mean by re-save permalink structure, if you mean something else please let me know